# Python Kivy 2 Buttons 2 Different Actions in Same Layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, kivy, kivy-language

I develop voice assistant with python and ı want to add basic gui with kivyy. 
I am writing basic gui with kivy and ı want to learn kivy framework so that ı am trying to improve myself with creating GUIs. But in this project ı have an error. Firstly, let me put my code here.

```
class Assistant(App):

def build(self):
    rl = RelativeLayout()



    b1 = Button(size_hint=(.2, .2),
                pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                text="Click For Exit!",
                color=(1,0, .15, 1))

    b2 = Button(size_hint=(.2, .2),
                pos_hint={'right': 1, 'top': 1},
                text="Run Program!",
                color=(8,1, .56, 4))


    image = Image(source="background_img.jpg")
    b2.bind(on_press=self.RunProgram)
    b1.bind(on_press=self.CloseProgram)


    textinput = TextInput(font_size=30,
                          size_hint_y=None,
                          height=100,
                          multiline=False,
                          allow_copy=True,
                          auto_indent=True)

    textinput.bind(text=self.on_text)
    textinput.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)

    rl.add_widget(image)
    rl.add_widget(b1)
    rl.add_widget(textinput)
    rl.add_widget(b2)
```

and for this two button there is their functions.

```
    def CloseProgram(self, event):
        sys.exit()

    def RunProgram(self, event): 
        while True:
              jarvis.run(listen())
```

As you can see ı have 2 button , one is quit from program and the other one is listen users. Also ı have text input that user can input something to give command from keyboard to assistant. But unfortunately when ı click "Run Program" button, Everything is good at first after when ı want to type something or if ı want to click "Exit Program" my GUI stop working. ( everything freezes and crashes ) but in the background my assistant continues to listen to user (me). How can ı solve this problem ?

İn this situation when ı delete while loop everything goes fine but when user wants to talk for assistant  have to click the "Run Program" button every time. Here ı want user can click buttons or can type to text input when program working on background. Thanks in advance.

More information:

I use windows10 , and python version 3.8.1

Comment: If you execute a `while True` loop on the main thread, that loop will hold the main thread and not allow anything else to run on the main thread. The main thread is where the GUI events are processed. To allow the GUI to run while also running your `while True` loop, you must run your loop in another thread. Have a look at [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#module-threading).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will check threading. I wish it will be work.

Comment: I solve my issue using Theread. Thank you @JohnAnderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using python **thread**. Thanks everyone.